# Android Studio Not Launching

Tags: android

[image: Error I am Facing]

Unable to Launch android studio 
also have tried to launch from root directory 
studio64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Try to install/reInstall

1. Microsoft Dot Net framework 3.5
2. Microsoft Dot Net framework 4
3. Microsoft Dot Net framework 4.5

then try to run the program "Run as Administrator"